# Java Generic doesn't infer the type

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors

I have written a code below which has a generic service abstract class which has most of the common functionality that the service needs to do for all of its implementation. All these messages needs to be verified and then passed on to the respective implementation class to do whatever they want to do with that object

But the problem here is that the Java Compiler is complaining that the argument **NotificationMessage** in my code below is of wrong type.

The child class

Can someone please advise why and how I can fix this?

My AbstractService class:

```
public abstract class AbstractService<N extends NotificationMessage> implements ServiceInterface {

    @Override
    public boolean execute() {
        NotificationMessage notification = controller.load(); //this call would return object of sub-type of NotificationMessage
        processData(notification); //Compiler complains here that the argument is wrong here

    }

    protected abstract void processData(N notification);
    }
}
```

One of the concrete service class:

```
public class SummaryService extends AbstractService<SummaryNotification> {

    @Override
    protected void processData(SummaryNotification notification) {


    }
}
```

Data objects:

```
public class NotificationMessage {
    public String getName() {
        return "";
    }
}




public class SummaryNotification extends NotificationMessage {
     public String getName() {
         return "";
     }

     public String getSummary() {
         return "";              
     }
}
```

Comment: the code you posted would never compile. please show us the actual code you are working on, or at least a minimal actual version which can reproduce the problem

Comment: You have typos in the code e.g. return has been written as retrun

Comment: This is the minimal actual code, probably did too much change while putting code here, but it is the same code that I have and yes there is a compiler error at _processData(notification);_, that is the query here

Answer (score 0):

Your method:

```
protected void processData(SummaryNotification notification) {
```

accepts a `SummaryNotification` hence you cannot call it with a `NotificationMessage` instance.

(Imagine if you're allowed to do that, in your `processData` method, you access method `getSummary` of `NotificationMessage` instance then runtime exception would occur)

So either:

1. Change your `controller.load` to return `SummaryNotification` OR
2. Make your `processData` accepts a `NotificationMessage` OR
3. Cast your `NotificationMessage` to `SummaryNotification` if you know before hand that your controller will return a `SummaryNotification` (this is not recommended)

Comment: Hi Manh, thanks for looking into my query. But, that's not a problem. I am passing the type from the concrete class, which takes its parameter. So call from concrete class is not the problem and if I were to take out my concrete class, the abstract class on its own doesn't compile because of the compilation error at processData(notification), which it should be call to its abstract method

Comment: @Ravi No, you're calling the method `processData(SummaryNotification notification)` with a `NotificationMessage` you got from the controller. There is no guarantee that will be a `SummaryNotification` which is why the compiler complains.

Comment: @Ravi you could not call processData with a `NotificationMessage` instance. Read the `Imagine` part.

Comment: @daniu, You are right here, that's why I am passing the type from the concrete class, which I was hoping that compiler will be able to infer the type. So basic idea that I am trying to implement is pass the type to the abstract class and the abstract class use that type which is always subtype of _NotificationMessage_ and call the _processData(N notification)_

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn, but then there is no reference to _getSummary_ in the abstract method, it simply pass it to the concrete class and concrete class knows the type of _SummaryNotification_, which it has defined at _public class SummaryService extends AbstractService<SummaryNotification>_.

Comment: @Ravi At the point of calling `processData(notification`) the type of the variable `notification` is `NotificationMessage`. It doesn't matter that the _value_ of `notification` is of a sub-type (`SummaryNotification`) because the compiler only knows about the type of the _variable_ (which again is a `NotificationMessage`). From the compilers point of view it _has no way of knowing that `notification` will always be, or ever will be, a `SummaryNotification`_. What happens if `notification` is actually a `DetailedNotification` which doesn't extend from `SummaryNotification`?

Comment: @Ravi Remember, Java is statically typed. The inference is limited to unambiguous declarations.

Comment: @Slaw, your point about "At the point of calling processData(notification) the type of the variable notification is NotificationMessage" that is correct and also "N extends NotificationMessage", so the call to the processData with NotificationMessage should work, which takes N as the type of the argument. No?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172976/discussion-between-slaw-and-ravi).

Answer (score 0):

Make the controller generic as well.

```
class Controller<N extends NotificationMessage> {
    public N load() { ...
}
```

and use the appropriate controller type.

```
public abstract class AbstractService<N extends NotificationMessage> implements ServiceInterface {
    Controller<N> controller;

    @Override
    public boolean execute() {
        N notification = controller.load(); // this will return the correct subtype
        processData(notification); // Now notification is of the correct type

    }

    protected abstract void processData(N notification);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, can't do that. It's an old legacy code and we don't own it as well

Comment: @Ravi In that case, you cannot be sure that the controller will create the correct `NotificationMessage` and the compiler is right to complain.